Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Embedding: {'input_length': 10}
I am trying to build this RNN below,
import keras

model = Sequential()

input_dim=3
output_dim=1
input_length=1

model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=input_length))
model.summary()

But the class Embedding doesn't recognize input_length as valid argument, however in keras documentations it is mentioned as example that input_length is used as argument.
I also tried removing input_length, I can't set weights as the model expects zero weights. So it's supposed to accept a value for input_length since its default value is set to zero.
I am stuck at this point, and I don't know if the developers changed anything. I am using the 3.1.0 version of keras. I also tried keras api in tensorflow and had the same problem.
The link to keras documentation: https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/

Can you verify that you actually have keras 3.1.0?

@drum Yes, I checked it using 'pip freeze' (Sorry for late reply)

use input_shape=(max_len,) instead of input_length=max_len
